# How to cast Map<String,List<dynamic>> to Map<String, List<DetailedPositions>>

Tags: java, flutter, dart, oop

I'm reading records from PostgreSQL and group cust_id level, resulted type is Map<String, List>. **Trying to convert Map<String,List<dynamic>> to Map<String, List<DetailedPositions>>** but facing Exception in fetchDetailedPositions type **_PostgreSQLResultRow' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.toString()** any help would be appriciated.

```
  Future<Map<String, List<dynamic>>> fetchDetailedPositions(
      String custID) async {
      await connection!.open();
      await connection!.transaction((fetchDataConn) async {
        _fetchMasterPositionData = await fetchDataConn.query(
          "SELECT cust_id, cust_name, net_quantity FROM positions");

        if (_fetchMasterPositionData!.affectedRowCount > 0) {
          fetchDataFuture = _fetchMasterPositionData!.toList(growable: true);
          Map<String, List<dynamic>> groupedPositions = groupBy(
              fetchDataFuture, (item) => item[0].toString() + ',' + item[1]);

          Map<String, List<DetailedPositions>> newMap = {};
          groupedPositions.forEach((key, value) {
            newMap[key] =
                value.map((e) => DetailedPositions.fromJson(e)).toList();  **--> code challenge here**
          });
          }});
    return newMap;
  }

class DetailedPositions {
  String custID;
  String custName;
  int quantity;

  DetailedPositions(...)

  factory DetailedPositions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DetailedPositions(
      custID: json['custID'] as String,
      custName: json['custName'] as String,
      quantity: json['quantity'] as int,
    );}}
```

Comment: can you `print("groupedPositions = $groupedPositions");`  before  `forEach`  on `groupedPositions` and show us the result?

Comment: groupedPositions = {ABC123,Test: [[ABC123, Test, 0], [ABC123, Test, 42]], WYN515,Gowtham: [[WYN515, Gowtham, 0]]}
  AND   
runtimeType: _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List<dynamic>>

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 Map<String, List<dynamic>> groupedPositions
```

to

```
 Map<String, List<DetailedPositions>> groupedPositions
```

Comment: fetchDataFuture throwing the error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DetailedPositions>'

          Map<String, List<DetailedPositions>> groupedPositions = groupBy(
              fetchDataFuture, (item) => item[0].toString() + ',' + item[1]);

Answer (score -1):

Try this code this will help you

```
newMap= groupedPositions.map((key, value) {
  return MapEntry(key, value.map((e) => DetailedPositions.fromJson(e)).toList());
},);
```

Comment: tried, still same error

Comment: whats the error

Comment: forgot to mention the error @MunsifAli.   "Exception in fetchDetailedPositions type '_PostgreSQLResultRow' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.toString()"

Comment: which line is causing this issue

Comment: Map<String, List<DetailedPositions>> newMap = {};

groupedPositions.forEach((key, value) {
newMap[key] = value.map((e) => DetailedPositions.fromJson(e)).toList();  --> here
});

Comment: I don't see any comments, do you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251322/discussion-between-munsif-ali-and-anilraj).

Comment: what happens? did you solved it?